# Proving $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{lcm(a_{i} , a_{i+1})} \lt 1 $ for a set of increasing positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, gcd-and-lcm

assume $a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{n}$ are numbers $\in \mathbb {N}$ such that $ a_{1} \lt a_{2} \lt... \lt a_{n} $; prove: $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}  \frac{1}{lcm(a_{i} , a_{i+1})} \lt 1 $$

Comment: What does $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$ stand for?

Comment: lcm I guess. @Meitar

Comment: Did you ask a question that you didn't even know the conditions correctly?

Comment: You should make sure that notations such as this be clear, either by using relevant terminology around it, or defining the notation you use. Have you considered induction? What can you say about $lcm (a,b)$? What other numbers could you take to as a bound?

Comment: Are $a_i$ different from one another?

Comment: @Meitar since it's given that $a_{1} \lt a_{2} \lt ... \lt a_{n} $, $a_{i}$s must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(a_{i},a_{i+1})} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{(a_{i},a_{i+1})}{a_{i}a_{i+1}} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{i+1}-a_{i}}{a_{i}a_{i+1}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{a_{i}}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}} = \frac{1}{a_{1}}-\frac{1}{a_{n}}<1$$